# Bond Price fraction convert to decimal 32nd excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

i am pretty sure a lot of people in capital market experience this :
use excel formular to convert fraction to decial in 32nd

i know most case we just divide last 2 digits decimal place by 32 for example:

100-160= 100+16/32=100.5
100-200=100+20/32=100.625

but if 3 decimal places : 99-226=99+(22+6/8)/32=99.7109375

how do we convert it to formula in excel , please help!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming a data setup like this where your Bond Prices are in column A and your formula for Decimal Conversion is in column B:

[image]

The formula in cell B2 and copied down is:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)+(MID(A2&"00",FIND("-",A2)+1,2)+MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+",4)&"000",FIND("-",A2)+3,1)/8)/32
```

Comment: looks good man, thanks a lot but what is there is 4th decimal place,lets say 100-1612

Comment: @wilson I have to admit, I've never seen a Bond Price that looks like 100-1612. What are the manual calculation steps and expected results?

Comment: @wilson In case you need the formula to explicitly be able to parse out after the dash for only the first three characters, I have updated the answer to make the formula more precise in that respect.

Comment: FYI  posted an alternative via FilterXML function (available in versions 2013 +)

Comment: This also works for prices quoted in the TradeStation format, e.g. 110'11.8  which can be written as 110-118 and then converted to 110.375  via the formula above.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Using FilterXML() function**

Adding a further column B with the following xml conversion

```
="<t><a>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+","4"),"-","</a><b>")&"</b></t>"
```

you can calculate results in a next column via `FilterXML()` available in Excel 2013+:

```
=FILTERXML(B2,"//a")+(LEFT(TEXT(FILTERXML(B2,"//b"),"000"),2)+RIGHT(TEXT(FILTERXML(B2,"//b"),"000"),1)/8)/32
```

**tl;tr - one column solution (just for fanatics)**

Of course you could also force the xml base into one formula:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><a>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+","4"),"-","</a><b>")&"</b></t>","//a") + (LEFT(TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><a>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+","4"),"-","</a><b>")&"</b></t>","//b"),"000"),2)+RIGHT(TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><a>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+","4"),"-","</a><b>")&"</b></t>","//b"),"000"),1)/8)/32
```